# Pandas Dataframe: grouping by index keeping only notnan value in each column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes similar to the following ones:

```
,A,B
2020-01-15,1,
2020-01-15,,2
2020-01-16,3,
2020-01-16,,4
2020-01-17,5,
2020-01-17,,6

,A,B,C
2020-01-15,1,
2020-01-15,,2
2020-01-15,,,3
2020-01-16,4,
2020-01-16,,5
2020-01-16,,,6
2020-01-17,7,
2020-01-17,,8
2020-01-17,,,9
```

I need to transform them to the following:

```
,A,B
2020-01-15,1,2
2020-01-16,3,4
2020-01-17,5,6

,A,B,C
2020-01-15,1,2,3
2020-01-16,4,5,6
2020-01-17,7,8,9
```

I have tried with groupby().first() without success

Comment: Looks like a groupby should do it - how are you doing the groupby and what results are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `grubby` + `first`

```
s=df.groupby(level=0).first()
              A    B
aaa                 
2020-01-15  1.0  2.0
2020-01-16  3.0  4.0
2020-01-17  5.0  6.0
```